# Electron <webview> back using backspace

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm writing an electron app. I used webview to show a website inside my app. I want the website inside the webview to go back when I press the backspace key. The Official documentary on webview was not helpful for me. How do I make the webview content go back when the backspace is pressed,please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have it not go back when you type backspace in a `<textarea>` or a `<input>`, than try this:

```
const webview = document.querySelector('webview')
webview.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=>{
        if(e.keyCode === 8 && e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'textarea' && e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() !== 'input' && e.target.contentEditable !== 'true') webview.goBack();
});
```

(If this worked for you, remember you can mark it as accepted by clicking the green check mark.)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
myView.executeJavaScript(`
    addEventListener("keyup", e=>{
        if(e.keyCode === 8) history.back();
    });
`);
```

(Uses ES6 arrow functions and template literals)

Comment: sorry, this didn't work. Here is the official documentation. [link](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/webview-tag/)

Comment: I figured it out and completed it. Thank you for the keypress code! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

So Finally I figured it out. Here is the final code.

```
const webview = document.querySelector('webview')
webview.addEventListener('keydown', (e)=>{
        if(e.keyCode === 8) webview.goBack();

})
```

Thanks for the keypress code. ^_^

Comment: There is a hole. If there is any textbox in your webview and you use backspace it will not accept that as backspace rather it will hit the navigation back.

Comment: I fixed that [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44390462/6560716).